# PDF reader for Word form control

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

I have a Word document containing several form fields (textboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes). I sent out this document for surveys and process the filled Word document programmatically to extract answers.

However, some user send this document in a PDF format which I have to input manually.

Is there any way I can programmatically read a PDF file (which has been generated from Word document)? Or is there any way I can convert the PDF file back to Word (and still have form fields (like textboxes and radio buttons)?

Open source / C# based libraries would be better.

Comment: Are you looking for something available at no cost or do you have a project budget?

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion PDF library capability to load the PDF document and extract the details of the form fields using our PDF library. For further information on how to retrieve form field details from a PDF document, you can refer to the provided sample and user guide documentation.

Sample link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/FormFieldSample-952469097.zip

Please refer the UG documentation for further details.

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms#creating-a-new-pdf-form

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms#filling-form-fields-in-an-existing-pdf-document

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-forms#fill-the-xfa-form-fields-along-with-acroform-in-a-same-api

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF file has form fields then almost any PDF library will be able to read them.

iText is open source but it is not free for closed source applications.

Commercially licensed libraries are quite a few. [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) is one of them, you read a form field like this:

```
PDFFixedDocument doc = new PDFFixedDocument(inputFile);
string fieldValue = doc.Fields[field name].Value.ToString();
```

Note: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET.